# Display image from Laravel to Html

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, react-hooks

How can I retreive image from laravel to plain HTML:
**Both laravel and HTMl running in different port**
Laravel Controller:

```
 public function imageUpload(Request $request)
    {
        $allowedfileExtension=['jpg','png','jpeg'];
        $file = $request->file('fileName');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $check = in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);
        if($check) {
            $file=$request->fileName ;
            $path = $file->store('public/images');
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => $path,
                'Filevalidation'=>True
            ],200);

        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Invalid File Extension",
                'Filevalidation'=>True
            ]);
        }

    }
```

Images are stored in **storage/app/public/images/ScTZ2rhj26sdJT3la5TKKsZ1DPbnbNl1YDuC3JrS.jpg** (This path)

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <img
      src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/images/C7o2dEHLlZLyP7RJewuiRsC4DiQ4oAyDxmPmJrsb.jpg"
      alt=""
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. at first you should link storage by running this command in console `php artisan storage:link`
2. then you can get image like this `<image src="http://your-url/storage/images/your-image.jpg">`

Comment: How can i link that..Could you pls explain or just we need to run that command.. We don't to specify the host address anywhere?

Comment: sorry, yes you should run this command in console, I edited my answer

Comment: Actullay laravel is running in separate port and HTML is running in different port. how can I link both

Comment: ok, in this way, try to write src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/C7o2dEHLlZLyP7RJewuiRsC4DiQ4oAyDxmPmJrsb.jpg"

Comment: Thank you bro... I was searching this from yesterday thank you bro